# net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, console

I am having a very strange issue with Chrome. When I try to access Google+ javascript doesn't work. So most things on the website dont works like changing settings and commenting. If I click f12 I see there is a lot of `ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` errors.

I tried running chrome in Incognito mode but that didn't work. I also tried reinstalling Chrome but that didn't work. I am running the latest version (58.0.3029.96). All other browsers work fine. I rebooted my router and computer, cleared everything except password in settings and did a reset. Nothing seems to work.

thanks for all your help!

Comment: Sounds like your connected to an insecure proxy which is performing a MiTM attacked

Comment: @Ramhound how do I fix that? what do you mean?

Comment: Determine if your using a proxy to connect to the internet or it.

Comment: @Ramhound I do not have any proxy's set up in "internet properties". And if I did wouldn't every browser have the same issue?

Comment: Chrome specifically cares about Google certificates more then any other certificate

Comment: Ok makes sense. So how would I know if i'm using a proxy. I said before that I checked Internet Properties. Is there somewhere else I should check? I didn't make any changes recently to anything. It just suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score -1):

I updated Java to the latest version and ran a scan with Malwarebytes. This fixed the problem! Everything started working again. Not sure what caused it?

thanks